# How to resize Image in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, image, image-resizing, sub-categories

I want to resized image of subcategory. for that,
I added this code in .phtml file.I'm getting wrong path for image

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $catId = 3;  //Parent Category ID
    $subCategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);
    $subCats = $subCategory->getChildrenCategories();
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    $count = 0;
?>
<div class="container homecat">
<div class="row">
    <?php 
        foreach ($subCats as $subcat) {
        $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
        $subcaturl = $subcat->getUrl();
        $_imgHtml = '';

        $subcaturl =  $_imagehelper->init($_category, 'image')->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
            ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
            ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
            ->keepTransparency(TRUE)
            ->resize('256','128')
            ->getUrl();
        echo $subcaturl ."<br/>";
        $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $subcaturl . '" />';
        $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        echo $_imgHtml;
    } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

I am getting

> http://Hostname/als2/pub/static/version1549014696/frontend/Theme/Name/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/.jpg

Comment: Bhakti, Please check my updated ans in detailed way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create resize image by passing image URL

> create Block file `app\code\Ketan\Resize\Helper\Image.php`
>
> pass url and dimension

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */


    

namespace Ketan\Resize\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Url;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Image extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $_response;
    protected $_resourceConfig;
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;
    protected $_filesystem;
    protected $_directory;
    protected $_imageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $resourceConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
        $this->messageManager=$messageManager;
        $this->_response=$response;
        $this->_resourceConfig=$resourceConfig;
         $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;
    }
    public function imageResize(
    $src,
    $width=35,
    $height=35,
    $dir='resize/'
    ){
        if (!@getimagesize($src)) {
            $src = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product/placeholder/'.$this->scopeConfig->getValue('catalog/placeholder/small_image_placeholder',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        }
        $absPath = $src;
        $imageResized = $this->_filesystem
        ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)
        ->getAbsolutePath($dir).
        $this->getNewDirectoryImage($src);
        $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create();
        $imageResize->open($absPath);
        $imageResize->backgroundColor([255, 255, 255]);
        $imageResize->constrainOnly(TRUE);
        $imageResize->keepTransparency(TRUE);
        $imageResize->keepFrame(true);
        $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(true);
        $imageResize->resize($width,$height);
        $dest = $imageResized ;
        $imageResize->save($dest);
        $resizedURL= $this->_storeManager->getStore()
        ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).
        $dir.$this->getNewDirectoryImage($src);
        return $resizedURL;
    }
    public function getNewDirectoryImage($src){
        $segments = array_reverse(explode('/',$src));
        $first_dir = substr($segments[0],0,1);
        $second_dir = substr($segments[0],1,1);
        return 'cache/'.$first_dir.'/'.$second_dir.'/'.$segments[0];
    }
}
```

In your `phtml` file

```
<?php foreach ($subcats as $subcat) { 
$_imgUrl = $subcat->getImageUrl(); ?>

<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('Ketan\Resize\Helper\Image')->imageResize($_imgUrl,'256','128','subtcat/'); ?>">

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: getting @Error filtering template: Warning: getimagesize(http://192.168.1.122/als2/pub/media/catalog/product/placeholder/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in D:\xampp\htdocs\als2\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\AbstractAdapter.php on line 304

Comment: upload place holder image in admin small_image_placeholder http://prntscr.com/mf6jlv f there is no image it will take from there

Comment: I got resized img of placeholder but I want subcategory image

Comment: be sure are you passing category image url in `$_imgUrl` otherwise it will take place holder image

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code for resized any images.

Using $objectManager :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$fileSystem = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');

$absolutePath = $objectManager->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::ROOT)->getAbsolutePath('pub/media/').$subcat->getUrl();
$imageResized = $objectManager->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('resized/'.$width.'/').$subcat->getUrl();         

//create image factory...
$imageResize = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory');       
$imageResize->open($absolutePath);
$imageResize->constrainOnly(TRUE);         
$imageResize->keepTransparency(TRUE);         
$imageResize->keepFrame(FALSE);         
$imageResize->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);         
$imageResize->resize($width,$height);  
//destination folder                
$destination = $imageResized;    
//save image      
$imageResize->save($destination);         

$resizedURL = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'resized/'.$width.'/'.$image;

echo $resizedURL;
```

Using Helper :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Imageresize extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{    
    protected $_filesystem ;
    protected $_imageFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_objectManager;

    public function __construct(            
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,         
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory         
        ) {         
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;               
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;        
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager; 
        }

    // pass imagename, width and height
    public function resize($image, $width = null, $height = null)
    {
        $absolutePath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::ROOT)->getAbsolutePath('pub/media/').$image;

        $imageResized = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('resized/'.$width.'/').$image;         
        //create image factory...
        $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create();         
        $imageResize->open($absolutePath);
        $imageResize->constrainOnly(TRUE);         
        $imageResize->keepTransparency(TRUE);         
        $imageResize->keepFrame(FALSE);         
        $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);         
        $imageResize->resize($width,$height);  
        //destination folder                
        $destination = $imageResized;    
        //save image      
        $imageResize->save($destination);         

        $resizedURL = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'resized/'.$width.'/'.$image;

        return $resizedURL;
    } 
}
?>
```

And then add following code in your .phtml

```
<?php $imgResized = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Imageresize')->resize($subcaturl,277,180); ?>
 <a href="<?php echo $br['link']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $imgResized; ?>" /></a>
```

Please check and let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code to resize product and any custom image**

Vendor\Module\Block\BlockName.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class BlockName extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    //upload image at -> /pub/media/directory/folderName/
    const DIRECTORY = 'directory/folderName';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $productImageHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_productImageHelper = $productImageHelper;
        $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    // to resize product image
    public function getImageUrl($product)
    {
        $width = 600;
        $height = 600;
        return $this->resizeProductImage($product, $width, $height,$product->getImage());
    }

    public function getProduct($sku)
    {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        return $product->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
    }

    public function resizeProductImage($product, $width, $height = null, $image = '')
    {
       return $this->_productImageHelper->init($product, 'product_base_image')
                ->setImageFile($image)
                ->resize($width, $height)->getUrl();
    }

    //for custom image -> upload image at -> /pub/media/directory/folderName/ -> path declared at variable DIRECTORY 
    public function resizeCustomImage($image, $width = null, $height = null)
    {
        $mediaFolder = self::DIRECTORY;
        $path = $mediaFolder . '/cache';
        if ($width !== null) {
            $path .= '/' . $width . 'x';
            if ($height !== null) {
                $path .= $height ;
            }
        }
        $absolutePath = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($mediaFolder) . $image;
        $imageResized = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($path) . $image;
        if (!file_exists($imageResized)) {
            $imageFactory = $this->_imageFactory->create();
            $imageFactory->open($absolutePath);
            $imageFactory->constrainOnly(true);
            $imageFactory->keepTransparency(true);
            $imageFactory->keepFrame(true);
            $imageFactory->keepAspectRatio(true);
            $imageFactory->resize($width, $height);
            $imageFactory->save($imageResized);
        }
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $path . $image;
    }
}
```

> 

```
IN PHTML
For Product:
<img src='<?= $block->resizeProductImage($product, 700, 700, $product->getImage()); ?>'>

For Custom Image:
Base Dir -> /pub/media/directory/folderName/yourImage.png
<img src='<?= $block->resizeCustomImage('/yourImage.png', 700, 700); ?>'>
```

> 

Answer (score -1):

I have written code for resizing any products images in Magento 2 according to your desired width and height. I will describe how to resize images In Magento2, Update product image in Magento2, Remove white frame in Magento 2, change product image dimensions Magento 2 such as needing to resize a custom image and display it on the site in special sized areas.

For Magento 2, you can use the following code to resize your images in Magento 2

Step 1: You need to create helper class file Image.php at Vender\Module\Helper\Image.php and the past below code.

```
< ?php
namespace Vender\Module\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Url;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
class Image extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $_response;
    protected $_resourceConfig;
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;
    protected $_filesystem;
    protected $_directory;
    protected $_imageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface $resourceConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
        $this->messageManager=$messageManager;
        $this->_response=$response;
        $this->_resourceConfig=$resourceConfig;
         $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;
    }
    public function imageResize(
    $src,
    $width=35,
    $height=35,
    $dir='resized/'
    ){
        $absPath = $this->_filesystem
        ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)
        ->getAbsolutePath().$src;
        $imageResized = $this->_filesystem
        ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)
        ->getAbsolutePath($dir).
        $this->getNewDirectoryImage($src);
        $imageResize = $this->_imageFactory->create(); 
        $imageResize->open($absPath);
        $imageResize->backgroundColor([255, 255, 255]);
        $imageResize->constrainOnly(TRUE);
        $imageResize->keepTransparency(TRUE);
        $imageResize->keepFrame(true);
        $imageResize->keepAspectRatio(true);
        $imageResize->resize($width,$height);
        $dest = $imageResized ;
        $imageResize->save($dest);
        $resizedURL= $this->_storeManager->getStore()
        ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).
        $dir.$this->getNewDirectoryImage($src);
        return $resizedURL;
    }
    public function getNewDirectoryImage($src){
        $segments = array_reverse(explode('/',$src));
        $first_dir = substr($segments[0],0,1);
        $second_dir = substr($segments[0],1,1);
        return 'cache/'.$first_dir.'/'.$second_dir.'/'.$segments[0];
    }
}
```

Step 2: Using below code you can call above imageResize() method from any class, block or template.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$imgpath = $objectManager->create('Vender\Module\Helper\Image')->imageResize('IMAGE_PATH','50','50','YOUR_DIR_NAME/');
```

Now I am going to explain the methods I have used
1.  getDirectoryRead()
2. getAbsolutePath() 
3. backgroundColor()
4. constrainOnly()
5. keepTransparency()
6. keepFrame()
7. keepAspectRatio()

Magento 2 – Properly remove white image from frame

```
< ?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>

•  
             helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(56); ?>" width="56" height="56" alt="< ?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />

    < ?php endforeach; ?>
```

If you want resizing image in magento 2 and you want further information about this then read our blog : [HOW TO RESIZE IMAGES IN MAGENTO 2?](https://i-verve.com/blog/image-resizing-in-magento-2)

Comment: Thank you, after solving the issue, I had written that blog :))